# Issue with rss feed

Tags: wordpress, rss-feed

I have a site with 2 stores (English and German) and 2 integrated Wordpress blogs (Fishpig extension). I want to display the rss feed of the English and German Blogs on a Wordpress website. The English one shows fine:
https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/index.php/blog/feed
The German one does not show:
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/feed
I modified the feed.php file in Wordpress by adding:

```
    $feed->force_feed(true);
```

But I think it's a Magento config problem. If I try to validate the URL it says that it looks like a webpage and not a feed. From the backend the actual URL of the German blog is: https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/WP/german
I tried to input that with "feed" at the end and still not working. I get this error:

> "This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML
>   error: Attribute without value at line 158, column 158"

I paste here the rss feed that is not recognised as a valid feed, which is identical (in terms of structure) to the one that works:

```
 <rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<language>en-US</language>
<title>Marsden Waagen Blog</title>
<description>Marsden Waagen Blog</description>
<pubDate>Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:55:32 +0000</pubDate>
<generator>
http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/?v=4.0.0.39
</generator>
<link>https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/</link>
<atom:link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/feed"/>
<item>
<title>
Sie ist hier. Die Zukunft mit der Patiententransferwaage.
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p style="text-align: justify"><img class="alignleft wp-image-1022" src="https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/WP/german/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/09/Patiententransferwaage.jpg" alt="Patiententransferwaage" width="300" height="180" /></p> <p style="text-align: justify"><strong>Seit Anfang 2016 arbeitet Marsden an einer komplett neuen Waage. Sie ist die Erste ihrer Art und eine revolutionäre Idee, welche die Art und Weise wie immobile Patienten gewogen werden verändern könnte.</strong></p> <p style="text-align: justify"><span style="font-weight: 400">Die Patiententransferwaage ist anders als jede andere Waage und wird im nächsten Monat auf den Markt kommen. Aber was ist es, warum gibt es sie und was bringt sie den Krankenhäusern?</span></p> <p> <a href="https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/09/11/die-zukunft-mit-der-patiententransferwaage/" class="read-more">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span></a>
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 11 Sep 2018 23:00:30 +0000</pubDate>
<link>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/09/11/die-zukunft-mit-der-patiententransferwaage/
</link>
<guid>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/09/11/die-zukunft-mit-der-patiententransferwaage/
</guid>
<author>Stephanie@marsdengroup.co.uk (stephanie)</author>
<category>
<![CDATA[
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/uncategorised/
]]>
</category>
<dc:creator>stephanie</dc:creator>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Die Bedeutung der Wiegung von Patienten bei der Aufnahme in ein Krankenhaus
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p style="text-align: justify"><a href="https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/news/9198132/Weigh-all-hospital-patients-as-one-in-four-is-malnourished-charity.html"><span style="font-weight: 400"><img class="size-medium wp-image-1027 alignleft" src="https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/WP/german/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/09/Krankenhaus-300x225.jpg" alt="Krankenhaus" width="300" height="225" /><strong>Alle Patienten sollten bei der Aufnahme in ein Krankenhaus gewogen werden.</strong></span></a><strong> Eine genaue Einschätzung kann das Ausmaß des<a href="https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/index.php/blog/2017/03/03/download-new-white-paper-accurate-assessment-patient-weight/"> Funktionsverlustes der Organe überwachen, die Wirksamkeit von Medikamenten einschätzen und die Berechnung von medizinischen Dosierungen ermöglichen.</a></strong></p> <p style="text-align: justify"><span style="font-weight: 400">In vielen Fällen ist es jedoch nicht einfach, einen Patienten bei der Aufnahme ins Krankenhaus zu wiegen.</span></p> <p> <a href="https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/09/05/wiegung-von-patienten-bei-der-aufnahme-in-ein-krankenhaus/" class="read-more">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span></a>
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 05 Sep 2018 23:00:32 +0000</pubDate>
<link>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/09/05/wiegung-von-patienten-bei-der-aufnahme-in-ein-krankenhaus/
</link>
<guid>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/09/05/wiegung-von-patienten-bei-der-aufnahme-in-ein-krankenhaus/
</guid>
<author>Stephanie@marsdengroup.co.uk (stephanie)</author>
<category>
<![CDATA[
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/uncategorised/
]]>
</category>
<dc:creator>stephanie</dc:creator>
</item>
<item>
<title>Produkt Highlight M-210 Stuhlwaage</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p style="text-align: justify"><strong><img class="alignleft wp-image-330" src="http://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/WP/german/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/10/Unbenannt-40.png" alt="M-210" width="300" height="260" />Heute möchten wir Ihnen unseren beliebteste britische Stuhlwaage vorstellen - die M-210. </strong>Sie ist in Großbritannien der Verkaufsschlager unter den Stuhlwaagen und natürlich zu Recht. Doch auch hier stellen sich die Fragen:</p> <p style="text-align: justify"><strong>Wer kauft sie?... und vor allem - Wieso?</strong></p> <p style="text-align: justify"> <a href="https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/08/28/produkt-highlight-m-210/" class="read-more">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span></a>
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 28 Aug 2018 23:00:16 +0000</pubDate>
<link>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/08/28/produkt-highlight-m-210/
</link>
<guid>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/08/28/produkt-highlight-m-210/
</guid>
<author>admin@marsden-weighing.co.uk (Marsden)</author>
<category>
<![CDATA[
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/medizinischer-blog-post/
]]>
</category>
<dc:creator>Marsden</dc:creator>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Bewährte Praktiken: Wie man ein Kind mit Behinderung wiegt
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p style="text-align: justify"><b><img class="alignleft wp-image-1016" src="https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/WP/german/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/08/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Kind mit Behinderung" width="300" height="200" />Adipositas bei Kindern wird als eines der größten Gesundheitsprobleme des 21. Jahrhunderts" bezeichnet - Marsden berichtete Anfang des Jahres, inwiefern </b><a href="https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/04/12/949/"><b>Großeltern zum Übergewicht der Kinder beitragen</b></a><b>. </b></p> <p style="text-align: justify"><span style="font-weight: 400">Ein Kind mit Behinderung ist besonders gefährdet. Schätzungen gehen davon aus, dass ein solches Kind zwei- bis dreimal häufiger übergewichtig oder fettleibig ist als seine sich typischerweise entwickelnden Altersgenossen.</span></p> <p> <a href="https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/08/20/bewahrte-praktiken-wie-man-ein-kind-mit-behinderung-wiegt/" class="read-more">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span></a>
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Mon, 20 Aug 2018 17:37:55 +0000</pubDate>
<link>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/08/20/bewahrte-praktiken-wie-man-ein-kind-mit-behinderung-wiegt/
</link>
<guid>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/08/20/bewahrte-praktiken-wie-man-ein-kind-mit-behinderung-wiegt/
</guid>
<author>Stephanie@marsdengroup.co.uk (stephanie)</author>
<category>
<![CDATA[
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/medizinischer-blog-post/
]]>
</category>
<dc:creator>stephanie</dc:creator>
</item>
<item>
<title>Produkt Highlight M-425 Flachwaage</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p style="text-align: justify"><strong><img class="size-medium wp-image-1009 alignleft" src="https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/WP/german/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/07/Marsden-M-425-300x300.jpg" alt="M-425" width="300" height="300" />In diesem Blog Post steht unsere tragbare Marsden Flachwaage M-425 im Fokus. Sie erfahren, was genau diese Waage ausmacht, welche Funktionen sie besitzt und natürlich auch, wie sie mit uns in Kontakt treten können um eine zu erwerben.</strong></p> <p style="text-align: justify"><span style="font-weight: 400">Bei den heutigen Ansprüchen in medizinischen Einrichtungen benötigen Sie qualitativ hochwertige und vor allem zuverlässige Waagen. Durch Eichklasse III und die Zulassung nach dem Medizinproduktegesetz erlaubt den einfachen und legalen Einsatz der Waage in medizinischen Einrichtungen. </span></p> <p> <a href="https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/07/24/produkt-highlight-m-425-flachwaage/" class="read-more">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span></a>
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 24 Jul 2018 23:00:36 +0000</pubDate>
<link>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/07/24/produkt-highlight-m-425-flachwaage/
</link>
<guid>
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/2018/07/24/produkt-highlight-m-425-flachwaage/
</guid>
<author>Stephanie@marsdengroup.co.uk (stephanie)</author>
<category>
<![CDATA[
https://marsdenweighing.de/index.php/blog/firmenspezifischer-blog-post/
]]>
</category>
<dc:creator>stephanie</dc:creator>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: have you fixed the error? Can you put your solution up here? I am also having the same problem